# What is the equivalent of default: in Shake

Tags: shake-build-system

I'm trying to use Shake as replacement for Make in small project. Currently it's mostly used for aliasing shell commands. Is there any way to specify default phony action? Something similar to default: in makefile. For example, given:

```
phony "build" $ do
    ...
```

I'd like to declare that if given no targets, it run the action for `build`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can write `want ["build"]`.

Long answer: there are a few things going on here:

- `action` defines something that will run by default.
- The function `want` is defined as `action . need`, so it lets you declare some files that you want to build by default. I rarely use `action` directly, since it's almost always a `want` you are doing.
- The function `withoutActions` takes a build system  and removes all the actions from it. You almost never need to call that, since...
- Provided you are using `shakeArgs` or `shakeArgsWith` (which almost everyone should be) then if there are any file-like command line arguments it calls `withoutActions` and `want` on the args you passed. If there are no file-like arguments the `action` statements are not removed and run.